# VBA error "91" (object variables not set) when I try to output innertext of HTMLelement

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to use the VBA to scraping data from the web site. First, i use message box to display the text, it is work. Then i try to output its into Cell it occurred error which i don't understand.

this is my code:

```
Sub macro()
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim web As String
Dim sale1 As Variant, a As String

web = "https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/bao-cao-ket-qua-kinh-doanh/vto.shtml"
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate web

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set html = IE.document
Set sale1 = html.getElementsByClassName("incomestatement_right_1").Item(0)
    MsgBox sale1.innerText
'when i try to put the code below into work it occurred error'
    Range("Q2") = sale1.innerText
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The MsgBox displays the innerText but the Range("Q2") gives you an error? When you run the code, are the Quotations marks removed completely from that line? `Range("Q2") = sale1.innerText`

Comment: yes, actually i just put quotation mark to highlight the code line.

Comment: instate of Range("Q2") = sale1.innerText , i also tried IE.quit. but the error still occurred

Comment: It seems that the error goes back to IE, you have not Set IE as an object.

Comment: i have tried, but it occurred error, i think i have declare IE as before as SHDocVw.InternetExplorer. I have the code with different web and different class name it working fine :(((

Comment: @shahkalpesh i have tried but it not work either

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? On what line does the error occur, if it does?

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment regarding using `Item(1)` instead of `Item(0)`. Using `Item(0)` gives me the value 439,147.

Comment: yes, i really need that value to be on the cell. The error is 91 which is "object or with block variables are not set". It shown on the line "Range("Q2") = sale1.innerText"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are using IE to request the plain HTML file that the web server delivers to your browser. It's an equivalent of navigating to the page and then viewing it's source code.

This however doesn't take into account any DOM manipulation that has taken place through the use of JavaScript for example. That's why `inspect element` is different from `view source`.

In this particular case, the HTML element you are interested in, which is:

`<table id="Listed_IncomeStatement_tableResult"></table>`,

is being populated by a script and its contents are not visible in the page's source code.

So basically your code gets the HTML code but the table's body is empty, which means your `sale1` is empty as well, because the element you searched for was never found.

What you need to do is to learn how to work with HTTP requests instead of IE. You'll be doing yourself a favor.

Go to the website, inspect the network traffic when you hit that orange "view" button...
[image: view button]

...and you will see that all you need is a "POST" HTTP request, which returns a JSON response containing all the data you need.

[image]

[image]

Search how to work with HTTP requests and use the information from your browser to replicate it:

[image]

Finally you need to search how to parse a JSON response using vba and you'll be set to go.